# How do I re- acquire focus in an edittext that is saving it's answer in the after changed event?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, focus, android-runonuithread

Here is part of the code:

```
    textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {                              
                       TextFieldFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    save();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    DELAY
            );
        }
    });
```

After the save() runs, my edittext loses focus, but I need it to keep focus.

Is more info needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 editText.setFocusable(true)
```

and remember to have 
`setFocusableInTouchMode` and `setFocusable`.